# Opencart contact form in footer.php

Tags: php, opencart

I have added a basic contact form into the footer of an Opencart theme. E.g I have:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') &&
(isset($this->request->post['enquiry_submit'])) && $this->validate()) {
```

This works correctly as expected. The problem now is that if you are on a different page such as Customer Register and try to send the Footer contact form I get a load of Undefined notices.

Comment: And where did You put the provided code? In which controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the code in the controller for the footer may seem like a good idea, however it does mean that you're then going to end up trying to post to the footer itself to guarantee its available every page, which is a bit overkill and bad practice. The way to resolve this would be to either:

- Get the form to post to the contact us form (information/contact route). This has the benefit of being coded already though does mean that your customers will be redirected to that page
- Use AJAX to send to either the contact us form or a new controller made to handle this, and use JSON to send back the result of the contact submission. In my opinion this is the better option for your customers

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is obvious:

1. You placed a code `if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') &&
   (isset($this->request->post['enquiry_submit'])) && $this->validate()) {` to a FOOTER controller that is processed maybe as the last one.
2. Before footer controller is processed there are more (up to dozens) controllers processed before
3. Almost every controller contains this code: `if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {` - thus almost every controller before footer tries to do their stuff when a form is submitted... And that is why You have a bunch of `Undefined index` notices...

I'd suggest:

1. Leave the footer controller to handle the form displaying
2. Display the form in the footer template
3. Edit the main contact form controller/template/language file:

   1. in controller add new function like `footer()` and move all the after-submit processing code from footer controller here
   2. add stuff needed into contact template and language file
4. In the footer's contact form make sure the form is submitted to this URL: `http://www.youropencartsite.com/index.php?route=contact/contact/footer`.

By this You ensure that when a contact form from the footer is submitted the user is redirected to a normal contact form where a concrete method is called which handles the submitted data and no other controller gets involved in the data processing...

Comment: Nice idea although I would prefer the user to stay on the same page when sending a message.

Comment: Then You would have to edit every single controller within frontend and add this part `&& (isset($this->request->post['enquiry_submit']))` to whenever should a POST be checkek and `$this->validate()` called (place it before `$this->validate()` to ensure that if the `(isset($this->request->post['enquiry_submit']))` is false `$this->validate()` will not be called...

Comment: As Jay suggested using AJAX to post the form.

Comment: Yep, read that later...Don't know how could it not come to my mind, I'm using AJAX almost all the time at work... :-)

Comment: Turning off error reporting is NEVER advised imo, its just lazy programming

Comment: @JayGilford That is true, but I only advised to turn off reporting of notices... Not the warnings or errors... Opencart itself does not know the `isset` function (metaphore) thus notices are very common here...

Comment: @shadyyx - Even notices shouldn't be turned off. All errors should be fixed, not just swept under the carpet. They are sometimes linked to the reason you end up with warnings, so its advisable to always have full error reporting. As for OpenCart having "very common" notices, that's not true. I use OpenCart for development pretty much every day, and its rare you come across them

Comment: @JayGilford I use it very often too, I think of it as of the best opensource eshop solution. And when implementing new functionality the notices are quite often pain in the ass - but I won't argue that is the problem between the chair and keyboard :-D